# How do you concatenate two variables for the text of a select.genericlist

Tags: list, select, joomla, concatenation, field

in this select.generic list I am wanting to concatenate two variables/fields for the "text" of this list. It is a functioning list.

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('select.genericlist',  $this->assets, 'id', 'class="inputbox"      onchange="document.location.href = this.value"', 'link',  'serialnumber' , $this->asset->link);?>
```

Where 'serialnumber' is the field used for the text of the list, I am trying to get 'model' AND 'serialnumber' so that it displays "Model: serialnumber" in the select list.

Everything i have found for concatenation does not work, and seems to just make a string 'model:serialnumber' which is a non-existant field.

using $model . $serialnumber is a no go as well, though using just one variable works fine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing would be you do a concat at the db level.
So when generating $this->assets you put something like this in the query:

```
SELECT bla1, bla2, CONCAT('Model: ', bla3) AS text ...
```

or

```
SELECT bla1, bla2, CONCAT(model, ': ', serialnumber) AS text ...
```

if model is a db field.

Comment: I was able to take your code as `   $query->select(
   $this->getState(
    'list.select',
    'a.id, a.name, CONCAT(a.model,\': \', a.serialnumber, )AS modelserial, ....') ` and it is working, except NOT in the select list. I can use "modelserial" anywhere else in the code and it works perfectly. I cannot for the life of me find anywhere in the model to affect the select list. So, the concat part is good, but I can't figure out where to change the query to affect the list.

Comment: ok, I found that I had to make that same change in the category model as opposed to the asset model. All is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Taking what Mike said I found where I needed to make the change to the query in the category model of my component. I wasted a lot of time thinking it had to be in the asset model:

```
$query->select($this->getState('list.select', 'a.id, a.name, CONCAT(a.model,\': \', a.serialnumber)AS modelserialnumber, ...
    $query->from('`#__asset_details` AS a');
```

Thanks Mike for your help!